# Identify Pivot Field using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I am trying to write a macro which automatically identifies which field is the data taken from in a pivot.

I have some columns with different level of org information dragged under one another in "Row Labels" to create a structure. Now I need to identify which row in the pivot is linked to which field.

I am a self-taught coder and am very new to advanced vba so need some help.

How my pivots look

[image: How my pivots look]

I am trying to get the name of the field in the blue circle

[image: I am trying to get the name of the field in the blue circle]

Thank you!

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve. What does the code read? What do you expect the output to be? What is your code so far?

Comment: Use the macrorecorder to record you selecting and re-arranging that field. Then see which field is noted in the code.

Comment: @teylyn I am sorry I wasn't clear enough. What I am trying to do is to create a code which reads all the values which are not 'blank' in the pivot row by row and pastes them in a separate sheet and also specifies which level are they part. My output would be let's say I am at cell A15 which says "Finance" and  i execute a command like "ActiveCell.FieldName". The output should be "Level 2". Does that make sense?

Comment: Why don't you just copy the Pivot to the other sheet, change Layout to Tabular, and filter out blank values?

Comment: @QHarr I am sorry, I guess I made that confusing. I am not trying to reorder. I am trying to identify which field does the row data belong to.

Comment: @jeffreyweir Great Idea, I can do that but that'd not tell me which field is the row data picked from. I'd need that information for something that I am trying to automate.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind guys, It was simpler than I thought. I am just an idiot for not figuring it out earlier.

Anyhow, the solution is that "ActiveCell.PivotField" returns the Pivot row's field.